# cookies disappear after page reload on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cookies, cross-domain

when you enter the site, cookies are set and everything goes fine, but when you reload the page, the set cookies are deleted

response from login(back):

```
    export const sendAccessTokenAndRefreshToken = (response:ServerResponse, accesstoken:string, refreshtoken:string) => {

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/json; application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
        'Set-Cookie':  [`refreshtoken=${refreshtoken}; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Path=/; Max-Age=99999999;`]
       
    });

    response.end(JSON.stringify({accesstoken}));

}
```

respons options (cors):

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/json; application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Authorization",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
});

response.end(JSON.stringify({message: 'Cors Work!'}));
```

when login is done:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e0c1.png)

after site reload:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exWO8.png)

in this picture you can see when sending a post request, cookies are displayed, but after a reboot it disappears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUK07.png)

front login.js:

```
    const body = {

    login: login_input.value,
    password: password_input.value

}

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', json.accesstoken);
```

How to solve this problem? I tried to use the cors browser extension but even that did not help

how to solve this problem without resorting to extraneous frameworks?

Comment: am having the exact problem like yours. Except the domain of the cookie is not 127.0.0.1 (seen on your screenshot) but abcxyz.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com. I wonder if your authorization service was really running locally, and if yes you wouldn't even need cross-domain cookie (samesite=none), right? But my main question is if you already found a solution and could kindly share it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect is the use of the ' and ` quotes in the code below:

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
'Set-Cookie':  [`refreshtoken=${refreshtoken}; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Path=/; Max-Age=99999999;`]

Remove the '` and also remove the []  you are not supposed to have that either.

Something like:

```
"Set-Cookie":  "refreshtoken=${refreshtoken}; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Path=/; Max-Age=99999999;"
```

then it is a different question if it is a good idea to store the refresh tokens in a cookie, but that's a different discussion.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: isn't it legal to use an array to insert multiple tokens? It works for me (usually)

Comment: I'm still learning, I'm asking for such a code. I just think it's not safe to store the locastorage token anymore, is it?

Comment: I store the refreshtoken in one of the links (I set it globally to check)

Comment: For the rules when setting cookies, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: @Tore Nestenius Can you please explain why storing refresh tokens as HttpOnly+Secure cookie is not the best choice? What is the better alternative?

Comment: I think this video says it pretty well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw  The idea of using a Backend-For-Frontend (BFF) enables that you can move all the complexities of dealing tokens to the backend instead. Simplifying the code in the frontend. Then, the question is, why would you want to store the refresh token using HttpOnly/Secure? with HttpOnly, you can't use the Refreshtoken in the browser anyway. Better to keep the refresh token on the backend.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks for the video link. I think it's very interesing because it didn't only introduce BFF and the benefits, but also underlined the fact that if frontends let session riding happens, nothing can help.

Comment: Here is another good video. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/05/12/securing-spas-and-blazor-applications-using-the-bff-pattern-recording/

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie does not have expiration date, the cookie is considered Session Cookie, which will be cleaned up upon refresh.

Another possible cause is the 'HttpOnly' attribute. My Chrome deletes HttpOnly cookies every time the user closes or refreshes the page even though the cookie is not yet expired.

Answer (score 0):

**IN SHORT:** You need to put expire time

Please change your Set-Cookie

```
Set-Cookie: your_refresh_token Expires=Wed, 14-Feb-2024 05:51:54 GMT; Path=/; httpOnly;
```

and add this header, to work with 'credentials: include' on frontend

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

on front-end side you did well doing this

```
 credentials: 'include',
```

but in this part of the code,  didn't follow the best practice

```
localStorage.setItem('token', json.accesstoken);
```

try to put your accesstoken on Cookie, and the browser will take care for you, sending your cookie to the server every request with 'credentials: include'

***Technical Explanation***

**Expire Time for Cookies** enhances security by limiting the lifetime of sensitive tokens, reducing the risk of misuse if they are compromised.

**Use Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true** When dealing with cross-origin requests and including credentials (such as cookies). This allows the browser to include cookies with cross-origin requests.

**Use Cookies for Tokens**. Instead of storing tokens in localStorage, consider using cookies. Browsers automatically handle cookies and include them in requests to the appropriate domains, reducing the risk of XSS.

***Environment of Test:***

- Frontend: Angularjs (using $http 'withCredential: true'), Node
  14.21.3
- Backend: PHP 8.3, Laminas framework
- Browser: Chrome 121.0.6167.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- SO: Ubuntu 22.04

***Sources:***

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies